# "Flask-CORS Not Resolving Cross-Origin Requests"

Tags: python

I'm having trouble resolving Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in my Flask application. Despite using the CORS extension, I'm still encountering CORS policy issues. Here's a concise overview:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    # Logic to fetch and return data
    return jsonify({'key': 'value'})
```

Issue:

When attempting to make a cross-origin request to "/api/data" from my frontend, I receive a CORS policy error in the browser console. The error message is:

csharp

Seeking advice on resolving CORS issues with Flask. Any suggestions or best practices for proper configuration and troubleshooting would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})  # Set specific origins if necessary

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    response = jsonify({'key': 'value'})
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization")
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
    return response
```

You can also use **Flask-CORS** to handle OPTIONS requests automatically by setting the **supports_credentials**

```
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}}, supports_credentials=True)
```